# Add a way for a beginner to edit a HTML site that is already created? Some kind of CMS?

Tags: html, content-management-system, client, edit

There is a site that is currently created, and it is written in pure HTML.

Here's my question: how would I implement some kind of backend so a beginner with NO HTML experience could log in and just edit the text, change tables, add pictures, very easy stuff.

Ideas?

I'm pretty goot with HTML, CSS, Javascript, and could learn a PHP scripty-cms-thing quickly.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just "port" the site into an existing cms like yoomla, drupal, umbraco (.net) or any similar cms?

Comment: Maybe, but how would I go about doing that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver the site is going to run on?
How is this currently configured, is it already running apache or IIS or anything similar?

In this case you need to do a couple of steps:
- download the cms you want to use, for php i suggest yoomla, for .net i suggest umbraco
- make sure you have database access since al cms systems need a database on either a mysql or mssql server
- Unzip all the cms files to the right folder on the web server
- most cms systems have a /install/install.php or similar kind of installation page, open this page in your browser and install the cms

Comment: Once the cms is installed, try to find a manual of some kind which explains how to do some configuration and how to create your site,
i believe this can be easily found on either the joomla or umbraco site.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a client who wants to be able to edit the content on their site without having to code or do ftp uploads, I've been setting them up with a free Blogger account so that the person can sign in and edit/publish posts. Then I use php to parse the RSS feed of that blog, and print out the parts I want on my client's website. It can get involved if you want to create a separate page for each post in the RSS feed, or if you want to customize how the content is displayed, but in general it's pretty doable. If you're worried about having duplicate content on the Blogger site, just display:none everything in the custom CSS area in the Blogger settings.

In this very simple example, I want to publish the title, date, and content for every post on the home page of my client's website. I'll paste this code right where I want that content to print out in index.php:

```
<?php
class BlogPost {
    var $date;
    var $link;
    var $title;
    var $text;
}
// load the feed
$xml_source = file_get_contents('URL OF RSS FEED');
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml_source);
// cancel if the feed is empty
if(count($x) == 0)
    return;
// look through the posts and save the content you want
foreach($x->channel->item as $item){
    $post = new BlogPost();
    $post->date = (string) $item->pubDate;
    $post->link = (string) $item->link;
    $post->title = (string) $item->title;
    $post->text = (string) $item->description;
    // truncate the date because it comes from Blogger with a bunch of crap on the end
    $pubDate = substr($post->date, 0, 17);
    // print the content. modify as needed. 
    print('<h1>' . $post->title . '</h1>
    <div class="date">' . $pubDate . '</div>
    <div class="post">' . $post->text . '</div>');
}
?>
```

Now, any time a change is published from the Blogger account, it will immediately be reflected on this site.